# Searchable placeholders in the input elements on Chrome for iOS

Tags: html, css-selectors, ios10, placeholder, chrome-ios

Is there a way to allow user to search placeholder text using the "find in page" browser function?

I understand I can just add elements with zero height that contain placeholder text, but that seems like a hacky solution. 
Perhaps something using CSS pseudoclasses?

edit: I should mention, so far this is only an issue on Chrome for iOS(10.0.2)

the code is very simple:

`<input type="text" placeholder="First Name">`

Here's the screenshot of Chrome:
[image: chrome on iOS find-in-page]

This is what I get when I search for 'first'

[image: chrome fail]

Comment: Check this link:-https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/p/placeholder-shown/

Comment: that allows me to highlight an input element, but using "find in page" still won't find it. for example, if that element is way down the page out of user's view.

Comment: Please provide jsfiddle exectly what you want?

Comment: @Raziasultana your code is fine, but open it in Chrome on iOS 10 and try searching for what's in the placeholder using 'find in page' option

Comment: @andrei Do you want to create a bug against Chrome for iOS? If so follow this link below and report. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/entry?summary=Issue%20Summary&comment=App%20Version%20(from%20%22Chrome%20Settings%20%3E%20About%20Chrome%22):%20%0DiOS%20Version:%20%0DDevice:%20%0D%0DSteps%20to%20reproduce:%20%0D%0DObserved%20behavior:%20%0D%0DExpected%20behavior:%20%0D%0DFrequency:%20%0D%3Cnumber%20of%20times%20you%20were%20able%20to%20reproduce%3E%20%0D%0DAdditional%20comments:%20%0D&labels=Type-Bug,OS-iOS,Pri-2

Answer (score 0):

```css
input {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 65%;
}
input:placeholder-shown {
  border: 5px solid red;
}
```

```html
<form>
  
  <input type="text" placeholder="Placeholder text" value="Currently has a value (not showing placeholder).">
  
  <input type="text" placeholder="Currently has no value (showing placeholder).">
  
</form>
```

Comment: that still doesn't work on Chrome for iOS (i have 10.0.2)

Comment: Ok sorry but i 'll try